# fabricjs loadFromJSON with subclass objects issue

Tags: canvas, subclass, fabricjs

I'm tying to render a some canvas objects that I previously saved on my database.

My issue is very similar to this one https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/1hykgQ0aVhE. 
Unfortunally the corrected jsFiddle is not working.

I'm using a custom subclass, the `LabeledRect` as described on fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/ 
I modified the name of `LabelRect` in `Labelrect` as suggested in the google group forum.

I tried using the `enlivenObjects` method but didn't resolve my problem.

I posted my code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/polybogdan/dor143xr/3/) and in the snippet below:

```js
fabric.Labeledrect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

  type: 'labeledRect',

  initialize: function(options) {
    options || (options = {});

    this.callSuper('initialize', options);
    this.set('id', options.id || '');
    this.set('label', options.label || '');
    this.set('htmlContent', options.htmlContent || '');
  },

  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
      label: this.get('label'),
      htmlContent: this.get('htmlContent'),
      id: this.get('id')
    });
  },

  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);

    ctx.font = '20px skf_chevin_medium';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
    ctx.fillText(this.label, -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2 + 20, this.width);

    ctx.font = "20px skf_chevin_medium";
    // Create gradient
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, c.width, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop("0", "magenta");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.5", "blue");
    gradient.addColorStop("1.0", "red");
    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillText(this.htmlContent, -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2 + 40, this.width);
  },
});



//fabric.Labeledrect.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
//    var _enlivenedObjects;
//    fabric.util.enlivenObjects(object.objects, function (enlivenedObjects) {
//        delete object.objects;
//        _enlivenedObjects = enlivenedObjects;
//    });
//    return new fabric.Labeledrect(_enlivenedObjects, object);
//};

fabric.Labeledrect.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
  fabric.util.enlivenObjects(object.objects, function(enlivenedObjects) {
    delete object.objects;
    callback && callback(new fabric.Labeledrect(enlivenedObjects, object));
  });
};
fabric.Labeledrect.async = true;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(100,100,200)',
  selectionColor: 'blue',
  selectionLineWidth: 2
});
canvas.on({
  'object:selected': selectedObject
});




function selectedObject() {
  var id = canvas.getActiveObject().get('id');
  alert("id: " + id);
}

function addArea(areaCode, areaID) {
  var labeledRectObj = new fabric.Labeledrect({
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    label: areaCode,
    fill: '#ccc',
    htmlContent: 'test html',
    id: areaID
  });
  canvas.add(labeledRectObj);
  canvas.setActiveObject(labeledRectObj);
}

$("#addArea1").click(function() {

  addArea("A01", 1);
});

$("#addArea2").click(function() {
  addArea("A02", 2);
});


$("#reload").click(function() {
  var canvasJson = canvas.toJSON();
  alert(JSON.stringify(canvasJson));
  canvas.loadFromJSON(canvasJson, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
  //the canvas is not getting rendered
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="addArea1" value="Area 1">
<input type="button" id="addArea2" value="Area 2">
<div id="canvas-container" style="overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:scroll;">
  <canvas id="c" height="400" width="300" style="border:1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
</div>
<input type="button" id="reload" value="Reload Objects">
```

The error that I'm getting is "*Cannot read property 'async' of undefined*"

Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I recently struggled with similar errors deserializing custom subclasses when calling loadFromJson, for example `"Cannot read property 'fromObject' of undefined"`, and what I learned may help someone else. By inspecting the 1.7.19 source, I discovered that I had to change two things about my subclasses:

1. My subclasses needed to be declared in the `fabric` namespace. Previously I was declaring them as members of another class.
2. My subclasses had to have a `fromObject` function, and it had to be declared separately from the subclass itself. Previously I was declaring `fromObject` in the parameter object passed to `createClass`.

Here's what a working declaration looks like:

```
    fabric.MyText = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Text, {
        type: 'MyText',

        // The following code results in "klass.fromObject is not a function"
        //fromObject: function(object, callback, forceAsync) {
        //    return fabric.Object._fromObject('MyText', object, callback, forceAsync, 'text');
        //},

        ... my specializations ...
    });

    fabric.MyText.fromObject = function (object, callback, forceAsync) {
        return fabric.Object._fromObject('MyText', object, callback, forceAsync, 'text');
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `type` property on the custom class was not named propertly. See updated [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/pyk28eyd/)

Comment: The added areas are still not getting rerendered by clicking the reload object button.